# Razor mostrar fecha de la tabla de datos

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, date, vistas

Uso VS 2017, tengo datos ingresados y cuando intento editarlos la fecha me aparece vacía. Lo que intento hacer es que venga la fecha que está guardada y que se pueda editar con el datepicker que he venido usando. El caso es que el datepicker es de un textbox de html y los datos los usa razor.

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FechaInicio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "Filtros form-control input-sm", type = "date" })
<input type="date" id="fechaFinal" name="fechaFinal" class="Filtros form-control input-sm" value="mo" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer debes llevar la fecha a texto y especificar el formato de fecha.
Intenta esto:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FechaInicio, new { @type = "date", @Value = Model.FechaInicio.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") })
```

o usar el htmlHelper para que MVC te genere la edición del campo

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaInicio, new { @type = "date" })
```

Comment: Voy a ensayarlo . Así lo resolví: (arroba)Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FechaInicio, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "Filtros form-control input-sm", type = "date" })